# Position line in a resume

Tags: macros, formatting, positioning, resume

I am new to LaTeX, and I want to create a command that will display my previous positions formatted appropriately in a resume.

The format I am looking for is this:

```
02.07.2009 - 02.07.2010           Soft Dev, IVM Corp
                                  Sunset, California, USA

                                  Duties included blah blah,
                                  blah.

03.07.2009 - 04.07.2010           Tech Spport, SupOrT inc.
                                  Sunset, California, USA

                                  Responsibilities and duties included blah blah,
                                  blah, and then blah, but somtimes blah and blah,
                                  and MySQL blah and C# and Java blah Python.
```

where everything on the right should be aligned.

I think I need a command that looks like this:

```
position(dateFrom, dateTo, position, location)
```

and then somehow also align the **responsibilities/duties** section.

Ok here is what I got so far:

```
\def\position#1-#2 #3@#4{\noindent#1 --- #2: \textbf{#4}, \em{#3}}
```

which allows me to use it like this:

```
\position 02.07.2008-02.08.2008 {Software Developer}@{Supre Core Computing Inc.}
\position 22.12.2005-12.01.2007 {Support}@{Telephony  Inc.}
```

However, I still don't know how to make the position (i.e. software developer) align with the following position (support).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options here. You can use `minipage`s to define your command, as the following example suggests:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\mylena
\newlength\mylenb
\setlength\mylena{4cm}
\setlength\mylenb{\textwidth}
\addtolength\mylenb{-\mylena}

\newcommand\Position[2]{%
  \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\mylena}#1\end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\mylenb}#2\end{minipage}\par\vspace{1em}}

\begin{document}

\Position{02.07.2009 --- 02.07.2010}{Soft Dev, IVM Corp Sunset, California, USA\\[0.5em]
Duties included blah blah, blah.}

\Position{03.07.2009 --- 04.07.2010}{Tech Spport, SupOrT inc. Sunset, California, USA\\[0.5em]
 Responsibilities and duties included blah blah, blah, and then blah, but somtimes blah and blah,
 and MySQL blah and C\# and Java blah Python.}

\end{document}
```

There's a number of classes already designed to typeset CVs, perhaps you would be interested in some of them: [Writing applications for a job/CV](http://www.laqee.unal.edu.co/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#applications); I personally recommend you [moderncv](http://www.laqee.unal.edu.co/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/moderncv.html).

Comment: Could you explain what the second "minipage" does - and why it aligns with the first one?

Comment: @drozzy: The second `minipage` is used for the labor information; its width is `\textwidth` minus the width of the first `minipage` so the whole `\textwidth` is used. The two minipages align to the top due to the optional argument `[t]`.

Comment: Oh, so it's kind of like floats in css. But how come when we start the third minipage (in the second position) it also does not align with the first two?

Comment: Also why can't you just write \setlength\mylenb{\textwidth-\mylena}, but instead must use \addtolength?

Comment: @drozzy: I don't understand your first question, which third minipage are you talking about? For your second question,if you load the `calc` package, you can use `\setlength\mylenb{\textwidth-\mylena}`; without `calc`, that assignment will produce an error.

Comment: By "third" i mean, when we use the \position for the second time, and it opens a "minipage" - that is the third time minipage is used - on the page...

Comment: @drozzy: at the end of the definition of the `\Position` command I included  `\par\vspace{1em}` which declares that a paragraph has been completed and adds some vertical space; when a new `\Position` command is issued, then a new independent paragraph begins.

Answer (score 3):

There are also some pre-made CV document classes like [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv). See also this [list of packages with the keyword vita.](http://ctan.org/keyword/vita)

`moderncv` has a `\cventry` command that takes 6 arguments, the first of which is set like you want the date to be. So:

```
\cventry{2000--2007}{Acme entreprise}{Duties included...}{}{}{}
```

Would set Acme entreprises in bold and `Duties...` in italics, with the dates to the left. Check out the [`template.tex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples) for pointers.