# Create environment inside another environment?

Tags: tables, environments, tabularx

Why can't I define an environment, that encloses another `tabularx` environment inside it?

For example, why can't I do this:

```
\newenvironment{customTabular}{
    % This is the begin code
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l l X}
}
{
    % This is the end code
    \end{customTabular}
}
```

and then use it like:

```
\begin{customTabular}
        Blah & Blah & Blah\\
\end{customeTabular}
```

Comment: I think you meant `\end{tabularx}` instead of `\end{customTabular}` in environment definition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `tabular` extensions are all based on hacking TeX's alignment system which requires some expansion intricacies (that's as much as I understand about it).  One trick which sometimes works is to use the control sequences one level below the LaTeX abstraction.  This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newenvironment{customTabular}{
    % This is the begin code
    \begingroup
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{l l X}
}
{
    % This is the end code
    \endtabularx
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\begin{customTabular}
        Blah & Blah & Blah\\
\end{customTabular}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: The `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` are in there because `\begin{tabularx}` begins a group *then* expands `\tabularx`.  But since `\begin{customTabular}` begins its own group you don't need it for this simple case.  I suppose if you wanted to have extra code after `\endtabular` that would not be affected by the contents of the environment you would need it.

Comment: Is there a good alternative to hacking tabular, for aligning paragraphs in table-like structure for example? As in my other question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14164/position-line-in-a-resume

Comment: why do you have `\begingroup`... `\endgroup`?

Comment: @Herbert: because `\begin{tabularx}` begins a group, then expands `\tabularx`.  I wanted the same thing.  But on the other hand, a group is begun by `\begin{customTabular}` too...so I guess you're right, it's not necessary.

Comment: @drozzy: your other question looks more like a description list with item heads rather than aligned paragraphs.  So you could use a variation of the `description` environment.  But résumés are a well known use case of LaTeX, and many classes exist such as the ones you were pointed to.

Comment: Thanks, but my intention was to learn-as-i-go, that is why i didn't use the premade ones. I guess I should've specified that in the question :-)

Comment: @matthew Thanks! That solved my problem exactly.  I wish I'd searched here hours ago.