# tabulary fails inside another environment

Tags: environments, tabulary

The `tabulary` package works fine in the setup below when I write out the table header explicitly. But when I wrap the exact same commands inside a custom environment, TeX halts at the `\par`, with this message:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \TY@get@body.
```

**How can I use `tabulary` inside this environment?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % need wider textblock for table                                                                                                                                         
\usepackage{parskip}  % everything flushleft with line spaces between paragraphs                                                                                                               
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule                                                                                                                                                           
\usepackage{tabulary}

\newenvironment{schedule}[1]
  {\textsc{#1}\par%                                                                                                                                                                            
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{llLl}                                                                                                                                                         
    \toprule%                                                                                                                                                                                  
  }
  {\end{tabulary}\par\medskip}

\begin{document}

% Version 1, commands written out, no problem                                                                                                                                                                 
\section*{Herr Dr. Professor}

\textsc{Classes}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{llLl}
\toprule
Mon., Wed. & 9--10:50 a.m. & Introduction to \TeX, \LaTeX, and friends & Knuth Hall 80\\
Tue. & 12--2:50 p.m. & Seminar: Procrastination through Macros & Lamport Auditorium 95\\
\end{tabulary}

% Version 2, wrapped in environment, will not compile
\section*{Herr Dr. Professor}

\begin{schedule}{Classes}
Mon., Wed. & 9--10:50 a.m. & Introduction to \TeX, \LaTeX, and friends & Knuth Hall 80\\
Tue. & 12--2:50 p.m. & Seminar: Procrastination through Macros & Lamport Auditorium 95\\
\end{schedule}

\end{document}
```

Version 1 by itself compiles as desired:

[image]

Comment: Use `\tabulary` and `\endtabulary` instead of `\begin{tabulary}` and `\end{tabulary}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The manual of `tabularx`, not of `tabulary`.

Comment: ... as it says in some  manual:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same problem as in [Create environment inside another environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14175/create-environment-inside-another-environment)

The `tabularx` manual says that in order to use the environment in the definition of another one, you have to use the “internal” forms `\tabularx` and `\endtabularx`. The same is true for `tabulary` although the manual does not specify it.

```
\newenvironment{schedule}[1]
  {\textsc{#1}\par
    \tabulary{\textwidth}{llLl}
    \toprule
  }
  {\endtabulary\par\medskip}
```