# Best way to create custom number of table rows

Tags: tables, macros

Is there any standard way of defining a class so that

```
\startTable
\newTableEntry{x}{12.1}
\newTableEntry{y}{11.1}
\endTable
```

can be done?

The result should be

```
x    12.1
y    11.1
```

Thanks!

Comment: your question is very unclear, you don't say what you want to happen. `\def\startTable{\begin{tabular}{cc}}`, `\def\endTable{\end{tabular}}`, `\def\newTableEntry#1#2{#1&#2\\}` might work, although it would be better to use standard `\begin` .. `\end` environment syntax.

Comment: I corrected the question. Hope I am not vague now :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you kindly post the comment as an answer? I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
 \def\startTable{\begin{tabular}{cc}}
 \def\endTable{\end{tabular}}
 \def\newTableEntry#1#2{#1&#2\\}
```

although it would be much better better to use standard `\begin` .. `\end` environment syntax and so not use the first two lines, you could still use

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\newTableEntry{x}{12.1}
\newTableEntry{y}{11.1}
\end{tabular}
```

note that especially `\endTable` as a command name is completely against lateX syntax rules, and could not be defined with `\newcommand`, but even if you changed that to be (say) `\stopTable` as corresponding to `\startTable` hiding the environment syntax just makes it harder for editors to offer context sensitive help and syntax colouring.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same for `tabularx` based table?

Comment: @KarthikNishanth ?? just replace tabular by tabularx{some width} in the above, what did you try?

Comment: I tried, but get the error similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287529/tabulary-fails-inside-another-environment I apologise, I am really a noob at this.

Comment: @KarthikNishanth oh sorry yes of course use `\tabularx{\textwidth}{XXX}` and `\end{tabularx}` not `\begin{tabularx}` in the first form, but really why do it at all, isn't it simpler to just use tabularx directly in the document, as in the second example above?

Answer (score 3):

For such simple things, plain tex can be nice too

```
\settabs \+x\qquad&RESULT\qquad\cr
\+ x&12.1\cr
\+ y&12.2\cr
```